# [java][eclipse] UI becomes unresponsive

Tags: eclipse

I'm a seasoned software engineer and have used eclipse for well over 10 years.  In the last week, Eclipse has decided to rebel against me.  I'm dumbfounded.

**Problem**: I'm getting periods of very long UI unresponsiveness - on the order of 3 to 10 seconds.  Generally, I'll be typing when the UI just stops writing text.  It can vary from displaying spinning circle to not rendering anything in the window. Workspace building also slows down significantly.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get tasks done!  Any help appreciated.

**Details**:

It appears to start 10 minutes or more after starting eclipse. If I restart, it'll be ok for a few minutes.

This can happen in during any text entry. Though it's especially bad on code completion cases (i.e. "dot, cmd+space). Eclipse can also become unresponsive during anything else (moving the cursor, changing tabs, scrolling, etc).

CPU is not maxed out, though it appears CPU is pretty consistently at or over 50% - so maybe eclipse as pegged one thread/core?

**Things I've Tried**:

Updated from Neon.3 to Oyxgen.2.  Deleted all projects from workspace and reimported.  Upgraded memory in ini to -Xms512m -Xmx4000m -XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m. Deleted some metadata from a eclipse resource dir (don't recall which).  Updated Java.  No change.   Haven't tried uninstalling all eclipse and reinstalling yet.

Setup:

Windows 10 Home (up-to-date), 12GB RAM, 64 bit, Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)

Comment: Check your task manager to see if another process is the culprit. I've had a similar problem and found that Kaspersky was eating up my CPU whenever Eclipse had a slowdown.

Comment: I have done that.  I've disabled my anti-virus (avast), file backup (dropbox, crashplan). I've even closed all my chrome windows and process.  No change.

Answer (score 1):

How large is your project? Do you build using Eclipse, or do you build externally?
If you notice a progress bar in the lower right side of the GUI during these periods of unresponsiveness, it's likely Eclipse's Build Automatically feature causing your issue. If so, it can be disabled under `Project -> Build Automatically`.

Comment: In my workspace, I have around 6 projects open, probably around 100 to 200 java files (with maven plugin). No big change in project size lately that would explain it.  I do use Eclipse to build and have it set to build automatically.  I run in this fashion for years without problem.  I hadn't thought to turn that off, but will do and see if it helps.

Comment: In my case, 5000+ php files. this was exactly the problem. Alsways happened, when I was typing quickly and saving often. It seems a bit, like old build processes are not killed before the next one is queued or something.
I did not have this problem under neon